# Database that can store list in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sqflite

is there any database that can store a list of things inside a column for flutter?
I know about blobs inside sqflite but I feel it's may bug.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) - it can store lists

> Hive is a lightweight and blazing fast key-value database written in pure Dart

Comment: Hive also has limitations about that: _Generic type parameters like Box<List> are unsupported due to Dart limitations._ [docs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/boxes)